# Published a library with jFrog artifactory, external dependencies not loading when using library

Tags: android, build.gradle, artifactory, android-library

I'm using jFrog artifactory to publish an Android Library. The library is getting published fine. But when I try to use it, the gradle dependencies of the library are not loading up.

My pom.xml already has those dependencies.

My library has two modules -

```
-app
-secondarymod
```

And this is my code in **main project level build.gradle** -

```
artifactoryPublish.skip = true

project('app') {
    artifactoryPublish.dependsOn('build')
    publishing {
        publications {
            aar(MavenPublication) {
                groupId = "in.mikkel.mainapp"
                artifactId = project.getName()
                version = "1.0.24"

                artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-release.aar")

                pom.withXml {
                    def dependencies = asNode().appendNode("dependencies")
                    configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each {
                        def dependency = dependencies.appendNode("dependency")
                        print(it.group)
                        dependency.appendNode("groupId", it.group)
                        dependency.appendNode("artifactId", it.name)
                        dependency.appendNode("version", it.version)
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    artifactoryPublish {
        publications(publishing.publications.aar)
    }
}

project('secondarymod') {
    artifactoryPublish.dependsOn('build')
    publishing {
        publications {
            aar(MavenPublication) {
                groupId = "in.mikkel.mainapp"
                artifactId = project.getName()
                version = "1.0.24"
                // Tell maven to prepare the generated "*.aar" file for publishing
                artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-release.aar")

                pom.withXml {
                    def dependencies = asNode().appendNode("dependencies")
                    configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each {
                        def dependency = dependencies.appendNode("dependency")
                        print(it.group)
                        dependency.appendNode("groupId", it.group)
                        dependency.appendNode("artifactId", it.name)
                        dependency.appendNode("version", it.version)
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    artifactoryPublish {
        publications(publishing.publications.aar)
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'https://mikkel.jfrog.io/artifactory'
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'mikkelcl-gradle-release-local'
            username = "***"
            password = "***"
        }
        defaults {
            publications('aar')
            publishArtifacts = true
            publishPom = true
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, in the package managers world, dependencies are never published. Only Artifacts does. The dependencies should be downloaded in the CI in the same way you download them in your local machine.

If the dependencies are your private code, you should build and publish them separately.

Otherwise, you should configure the dependencies repository on your `build.gradle` file. In that case, please make sure that the repository is configured in the `repositories` clause.

Read more about Declaring repositories in Gradle [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html).

Comment: I was able to achieve this by using, transitive=true for time being